# Multiple applications built from one directory

Tags: go

I have a simple Go project which is a web application, a worker application, and a shared file. These are in files web.go, worker.go, and shared.go (for example).

How can I "go install" to create the 2 binaries from this setup? If I just put all 3 files together, I get error `main redeclared in this block` because I have 2 main functions in the same package.

I really don't want to split these 3 files into 3 different directories with the 2 entry points in subdirectories created just to seperate them logically.

How can I keep them in the same directory and compile 2 executables?

Comment: That's what you have to do. Each binary its own directory.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The clean solution is to create three separate directories. One for the web program, one for the worker program and a shared package for both of them.

Alternatively, you can also use [build constraints](http://golang.org/pkg/go/build/#hdr-Build_Constraints) to control your build. GAE uses this approach for example, by providing an "appengine" build tag that can be used to provide a different main when using GAE. In this case, you would need to add an arbitrary build tag to the beginning of your files (e.g. `// +build worker`) and invoke the go build tool accordingly, by including your build tags (something like `go build -tags worker`) should probably work.

Comment: @Greg Ennis Notice that you should not use build tags for everything but platform-specific code as they make your code no longer go gettable, i.e. manual intervention is required when building your package which is not a good thing.

Comment: Yes I did come to that conclusion also, after reading more about how build tags are used. And for example SublimeGo doesn't seem to support building with different tags. So I won't bother with that. Just use subdirectories I think. Thanks for the clarification.